# HTTPS request in twisted that checks the certificate

Tags: python, ssl, https, twisted, twisted.web

In my twisted app I want to make an asynchronous request to Akismet to check for spam. Akismet reasonably uses HTTPS, so I've been following the [web client guide on SSL](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/14.0.1/web/howto/client.html#http-over-ssl) in the docs. But there's this part that worries me:

> Here’s an example which shows how to use Agent to request an HTTPS URL with no certificate verification.

I very much want certificate verification to prevent Man-In-The-Middle attacks. So how do I add it?

My test code without verification is this:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web.client import Agent
from twisted.internet.ssl import ClientContextFactory

class WebClientContextFactory(ClientContextFactory):
    def getContext(self, hostname, port):
        print( "getting context for {}:{}".format( hostname, port ) )
        # FIXME: no attempt to verify certificates!
        return ClientContextFactory.getContext(self)

agent = Agent( reactor, WebClientContextFactory() )

def success( response ):
    print( "connected!" )
def failure( failure ):
    print( "failure: {}".format( failure ) )
def stop( ignored ):
    reactor.stop()

agent.request( "GET", "https://www.pcwebshop.co.uk/" )\ # uses self-signed cert
.addCallbacks( success, failure )\
.addBoth( stop )

reactor.run()
```

I'd like it to fail due to inability to verify the cert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm using Twisted 15.1.0.

Actually, the default init function of `Agent` will pass in `BrowserLikePolicyForHTTPS` as contextFactory and have the ablility to verify server certificate.

Simply using this:

```
agent = Agent( reactor )
```

will produce the following error:

```
failure: [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames):     
<class 'twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived'>:
[<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'OpenSSL.SSL.Error'>>]]
```

Make sure you installed `service_identity` package using pip.

---

If you need custom cert verification, you can create a custom policy by passing the pem in, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26166444/twisted-python-how-to-create-a-twisted-web-client-browserlikepolicyforhttps-with):

```
customPolicy = BrowserLikePolicyForHTTPS(
    Certificate.loadPEM(FilePath("your-trust-root.pem").getContent())
)
agent = Agent(reactor, customPolicy)
```

Comment: I initially did that, but also got the mentioned error when connecting to https://www.google.com.

Comment: Interestingly, that false negative only happens on my Windows development machine. My Ubuntu server happily executes either?! I've also tried a different website that's definitely self-signed with the same result.

Comment: This `BrowserLikePolicyForHTTPS` will use the certs provided by the system. Maybe that's why the results are different between Ubuntu and Win.

Comment: That sounds possible, but I never installed any certs on the Ubuntu machine, and certainly not those for the self-signed sites.

Comment: That's because Ubuntu comes with `ca-certificates` package installed, without which you can't even browse websites with valid cert like SO and Github.

Comment: I'm still a little worried sites I thought were self-signed work, but I'll just assume everything is okay then, security isn't really critical in this case anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for pointing this out.  This seems to be a bug in the documentation.  Prior to version 14.0, it was accurate; Twisted would not validate HTTPS, and that was a big problem.  However, as you can see in [the release notes for that version](http://labs.twistedmatrix.com/2014/05/twisted-1400-released.html), Twisted (at least in versions 14.0 and greater) does validate TLS on HTTPS connections made with `Agent`.  (It still does not do so for `getPage`, the old, bad, HTTP client; do not use `getPage`.)

I have filed [this bug](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/7879) to track fixing the documentation to be accurate.